# Trouble shooting Oracle Form Builder error FRM-10044

Tags: forms, oracle

I'm trying to create & save a new form using Oracle Form builder however, I get the error FRM-10044: Cannot create file.

The same thing happens when I open and save an existing form (.fmb)

I've check the folder permissions where the form is being save, it has read write access.

I've tried saving it into a differ folder and also tried creating a new folder but it still throws the same error.

I'm able to create and save a word, excel document in the new or existing folders (as mentioned-above) without any issues.

I suspect it could be something to do with the Windows Registry or System Configuration settings because I had recently shutdown/disabled so of the services in the System Configuration (using
msconfig.exe). Unfortunately, I don't remember all the options that were modified.

I've gone through numerous discussion forums, but still no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What if you uninstall and install Oracle Forms again ? When you uninstall, do have a look at the services which are left (if any), and do such AFTER doing a reboot of the machine, no matter what the uninstallation procedure says.

Comment: Oracle Forms has been setup using by copying the Orant folder (containing Oracle Forms) from another machine and modifying the Windows 7 registry. Therefore, uninstalling approach is not possible. We have been following this approach on other Windows 7 machines and it has been working fine on them. This approach even works on Windows 8. I have compared the windows services  and registry setting on both the machines however, did not find an difference. I suspected it could be UAC issue but it does not seem to be an issue because the windows user account type is "Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same thing. But in my case, i compiled the form on server side. The error appeared because it was remote-controlled by more than 1 person. One of the remote session was possibly locking the file creation. So I logged off the other session and try to use 1 session only when compiling the form. This happens sometimes when we're using an OS with multiuser and multisession capability.