# ROS ERROR : 0 , FRM-10044 : Cannot create file

Tags: forms, oracle11g, oracleforms

In oracle forms builder 11g,if i add new field and save the forms builder, then the above error is showing and its **not allowing me to save** the form.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356832/trouble-shooting-oracle-form-builder-error-frm-10044

Answer (score 0):

No other option left, other than re-creating a new form again. I have faced a similar case and it worked for me by copying the entire objects to a new form (Data Block, Trigger, Program Units, LOV's, et...). It worked well.

Comment: But, Its allowing if i remove some existing objects. Since its just 23MB of size, its not allowing.Even i've 28MB+ fmb which was working fine with new addition. Anyhow, It should have some specific reason. Thats we want to figure out to fix.